# Spring boot debug through the docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, debugging

I have spring boot service. i need to debug the service. but it is in docker container.

I followed the guide lines from [here](https://ckinan.com/blog/remote-debug-spring-boot-docker-intellij/) but unfortunately I end up with some error.

My docker compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  #Retaining mongo configuration even though we dont have repository
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "5671:5671"
    - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: root
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: root
  csig-generation:
    build: .
    container_name: "docker-app"
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '5005:5005'
    environment:
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Debug configuration in intellij

[image]

Running docker details
[image]

After attaching the debugger in intellij. the below output is got.

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'

But when I am trying to access the  API URL `http://localhost:8080/test/amtest` getting below error. Can anyone spot what is the mistake I did here.

[image]

Comment: Did you do k8s port-forwarding?

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov no I didn't

Comment: try out with - kubectl port-forward <<POD_NAME>> 5005:5005